# CakePHP how to redirect to a page after login

Tags: cakephp

So I made the application so every time I try to visit a page on it it redirects me to login, thats good, but after I log in I want it to redirect me to a certain page, but it doesnt, it just sends me back to page it redirected me from. I used the code from CakePHP cookbook for login:

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Buslines',
                'action' => 'index',
            ]);

        return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }
```

Now all I need to know is how do I redirect to buslines/index after login.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly requesting the `redirect` query variable and use it for redirection, so what you're seeing is the expected behavior, as that query variable contains the previously visited endpoint where access was denied. The second argument, the default value, will never be used unless the `redirect` query variable somehow gets lost.

Note that this redirect is only for when authentication was successful, so if you always want to redirect to a fixed endpoint after successful authentication, then just pass the corresponding value directly to `redirect()`, eg:

```php
return $this->redirect([
   'controller' => 'Buslines',
   'action' => 'index',
]);
```

You also don't have to configure the authentication service's `queryParam` option then.